# Button drawableStart draws outside of background border/corners

Tags: java, android, xml, button, drawable

I want to make an a bit circular button with a drawableStart (without padding).

I added this to the button background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#CC232323"/>

    <corners android:radius="50sp"/>

</shape>
```

The button is:

```
<Button
       android:id="@+id/btn_play"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="50sp"
       android:layout_marginStart="25sp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="25sp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"
       android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_layer_list"
       android:text="@string/sample_text"
       android:textAlignment="textStart"
       android:textAllCaps="false"
       android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
```

The layer-list is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/background_design"
        android:height="50sp"
        android:width="50sp"
    />

</layer-list>
```

the corner does work on the button it self but the drawableStart is not affected by them, so I get a button that on one side is with circular border and on the other side a square border of the drawableStart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple and easy solution, the idea of it is to wrap the button with a `CardView` and set it's `cardCornersRadius` to the wanted radius.

like so:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
      android:layout_width="150dp"
      android:layout_height="150dp"
      app:cardCornerRadius="250dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center">

        <Button
          android:id="@+id/btn_play"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="50sp"
          android:layout_marginStart="25sp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="25sp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"
          android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_layer_list"
          android:text="@string/sample_text"
          android:textAlignment="textStart"
          android:textAllCaps="false"
          android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"/>

   </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

it is without a doubt the simplest way I've found in order to get the view act withthin the borderd, the `CardView` will not let the button or anything within it to draw outside of its borders / corners.

For more information about `CardView` (it's properties, dependency, etc...), go to [This](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/cardview) link.

Answer (score 1):

View (or Button in your case) is always rectangle. When you apply background with rounded corners, it is only background image rounded, not the View itself. If you need to have rounded corners in drawableStart, you need to have rounded corners in drawable you set for drawableStart.

Comment: Do you know how can I do that? how can I apply the corners to the drawableStart it self or even apply it to the button it self like reconstruct it in some way?

Comment: I believe, there is no simple way to achieve that. You will have to mask image with [PorterDuff](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode)